# Detect code line of parameter string

Tags: java, logging, metaprogramming, meta, line-numbers

I want to have a method to quickly dump detailed information to a log. It'll be something like this:

```
public static void log(String message, Class<?> sourceClass){
    dump(formattedTime+sourceClass.getName()+"line"+lineNumberfromwhichthemessagecomes 
    (if several occurences are found, show all of them if there's no other way to
    detectwhere has the method been called from).
}
```

I already know that trick about creating a new Exception object and getting the line number of the first line of its stack trace, but by using that I would have to add the line number as a parameter because if you do the trick inside the **log** method, you will always get the same line number (the one of the line you make the trick in).

Is there any way to achieve this)?

Comment: Couldn't you do get the second line in stead of the first, and take that linenumber? Than you could keep your logic within the logger itself.

Comment: You should not be using exceptions at all. Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() avoids the costly exceptions and gives you the same stack information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Exception's getStackTrace() method to get a list of the stack frames. Then you can move up the stack either by 1 element or using some logic (e. g. until you get a method that's not in your logging class) and use the line number from that StackTraceElement for your logging.